# Show that $H_k(S^n,x) \to H_k(S^n,E^+_n)$ is isomorphic for all k

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am working on the proof that for all $k$ and for all $x \in S^n$
$$H_k(S^n,x) \to H_k(S^n,E^+_n)$$
is isomorphic, where we denote by $E^+_n$ the upper hemisphere of $S^n$.

The proof use the long exact sequence of $(S^n,E^+_n)$, where we can use the fact that $E^+_n$ is contractible and hence find that we have that for all $k>1$ we have $H_k(S^n) \to H_k(S^n,E^+_n)$ is isomorphic. Well now we consider the case where $k=1$:
$$\dots \to 0=H_1(E^+_n) \to H_1(S^n) \to H_1(S^n,E^+_n) \to H_0(E^+_n) \to H_0(S^n) \to H_0(S^n,E^+_n)\to \dots$$
By exactness we get that $H_1(S^n) \to H_1(S^n,E^+_n)$ has to be injective but the claim is that it is isomorphic... What do I oversee that we can conclude that and how does $H_k(S^n) \to H_k(S^n,E^+_n)$ helps me to show that $H_k(S^n,x) \to H_k(S^n,E^+_n)$ is isomorphic?

Many thanks for some help!

Comment: The long exact sequence of the triple $(S^n, E_n^+, x)$ should do it, in case you're familiar with that.

Comment: Why do you ask twice the same question? See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4351999 which was already answered January 9.

Comment: I closed your question as a duplicate. DO NOT ASK a question more than once, this is not well-received in math.stackexchange. If the answers to your first question are not satisfying, ask the authors for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

I think we should use the fact $\widetilde{H_n}(X)\cong H_n(X,x)$ for any topological space $X$ and any $x\in X$.

As you observed we have to verify it for $k=0,1$. We have
$$\dots \to 0 \to H_1(S^n) \to H_1(S^n,E^+_n) \to H_0(E^+_n) \to H_0(S^n) \to H_0(S^n,E^+_n)\to 0$$

For sure $H_0(E^+_n) \cong H_0(S^n)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and the map between them is an isomorphism because it sends the generator of $H_0(E^+_n)$ to the genertor of $H_0(S^n)$: the generators of $H_0$ are points in the connected components, and the inclusion of $E^+_n$ in $S^n$ sends a generator to a generator.

From exactness we have a sequence $0\to H_0(S^n,E^+_n)\to 0$, and so $$H_0(S^n,E^+_n)=0\cong \widetilde{H_0}(S^n)\cong H_0(S^n,x)$$

From the first part of the sequence and always for exactness we have
$$0 \to H_1(S^n) \to H_1(S^n,E^+_n)\to 0$$
and so
$$H_1(S^n,x) \cong \widetilde{H_1}(S^n)\cong H_1(S^n) \cong H_1(S^n,E^+_n).$$

This is what I think we should do.